# Multiple counts with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I want to retrieve and display on one row, the number of sales made by an employee followed by the total number of sales.

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesID) AS SalesForEmployee, COUNT(SalesID) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales
WHERE EmployeeID = 123
```

How do I make it so that the where clause only applies to the first column in the select?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `where` that only applies to one column.

In order to get both counts while only scanning the table once, you can do this:

```
select 
    sum(case when EmployeeID=123 then 1 else 0 end) as SalesForEmployee, 
    Count(SalesID) as TotalSales
from Sales
```

There's no `where` clause because `Count(SalesID)` needs to count every row to give you the total count.

Since you have to look at every row, `case when EmployeeID=123 then 1 else 0 end` gives you a `1` for each row that belongs to the target employee and a `0` for every row that doesn't. Therefore, summing that expression gives you the count only for that employee.

```
SalesID     EmployeeID (case when ... )
1           123         1
2           311         0
3           333         0
4           123         1
5           300         0
count = 5               sum = 2
```

You could also do it like this:

```
select
    (select count(SalesID) from Sales where EmployeeID=123) as SalesForEmployee,
    (select count(SalesID) from Sales) as TotalSales
```

But now you are scanning the `Sales` table twice, which will be slower.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Althought I'm not too sure why it works. I don't really understand why you need a sum and case?

Comment: I expanded my answer, hope it helps a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when EmployeeID = 123 then 1 else 0 end) AS SalesForEmployee
 ,COUNT(SalesID) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales
```

Comment: Blorgbeard was ahead of me in just a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(SalesEmp.SalesID) AS SalesForEmployee count(Sales.salesID) As TotalSales 
from Sales left outer join Sales as SalesEmp
on Sales.salesID=SalesEmp.SalesID
and SalesEmp.EmployeeID = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested subquery approach combining two select statements into one.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(SalesID) FROM Sales WHERE EmployeeID = 123) AS SalesForEmployee, 
    (SELECT COUNT(SalesID) FROM Sales) AS TotalSales
```

Another way to write it would be like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesID) AS SalesForEmployee, 
    (SELECT COUNT(SalesID) FROM Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales WHERE EmployeeID = 123
```

With a correlated subquery, you can link the outer query with the inner query. Say you wanted to get the Total sales not including the sales of EmployeeID 123

```
SELECT COUNT(SalesEmployee.SalesID) AS SalesForEmployee, 
    (SELECT COUNT(SalesID) FROM Sales WHERE Sales.EmplyeeID <> SalesEmployee.EmployeeID) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales As SalesEmployee WHERE SalesEmployee.EmployeeID = 123
```

Here the inner query is referencing the outqueries EmployeeeID in the WHERE clause to filter them out.

Comment: Please, explain better your answer